# how to count the frequency of two occurances at the same time?

Tags: perl

So i have a data set that looks like this:

```
2,1,10,2,0
2,1,23,2,1
2,3,6,2,0
5,1,4,3,0
5,2,2,2,0
5,2,2,3,1
5,2,8,1,2
5,3,6,3,1
8,2,12,1,0
```

I am trying to have perl print the last value for each occurance of the first 2 values in each line. So for instance it is my goal to have it print the following:

```
2 1: 0 1
2 3: 0
5 1: 0
5 2: 0 1 2
5 3: 1
8 2: 0
```

how do i tell perl to print the last value of the row for each occurance of the pairing of the numbers?

Comment: Are you actually trying to count the frequency of each permutation as your title suggests?

Comment: I need to count the frequency in order to tell perl to execute for each frequency of each pairing. (if that makes any sense)

Comment: Ok, so what does that have to do with the body of your question? I don't see anything about counting the frequency of the pairs. I would expect the frequency of `2,1` to be 2, not `0 1`, since `2,1` appears twice in your sample data.

Comment: ok so my over all problem is getting perl to get the frequency of each pairing and then printing it as "firstvalue secondvalue: lastvalue"

Comment: but my more specific question that i am stuck on is actually getting perl to count the frequency first

Comment: That's called an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and you'll usually get much better answers by explaining your end goal instead of how you're trying to do it. Am I right that you're trying to get `2 1: 2`, `2 3: 1`, `5 1: 1`, `5 2: 3`, etc? Or do you want to store the frequency somewhere (without outputting it) and output the last value found for each match?

Comment: my apologies. I am trying to store the frequency somehere (without outputting it) and out the last value for each row with each of the respecting pairing....i.e: `2 1: 0 1 \n 2 3: 0 \n` etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use strict;
#use Data::Dumper;
my $h;

while (<>){
    chomp;
    my @linechars = split /,/;
    #Use the first two characters of the input line as the key to a hash.
    my $key = $linechars[0]." ".$linechars[1];
    #stick the last character into an array for this key
    push @{$h->{$key}}, $linechars[4];
}

#print Dumper($h);

foreach my $key (keys%{$h}){
    print "$key:";
    foreach (@{$h->{$key}})
    {
        print " $_";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Gives

```
-bash-3.2$ perl tmp.pl tmp.txt
5 1: 0
2 3: 0
8 2: 0
2 1: 0 1
5 2: 0 1 2
5 3: 1
```

If you just want the frequency, replace

```
    foreach (@{$h->{$key}})
    {
        print " $_";
    }
```

with

```
    print scalar (@{$h->{$key}})."\n"
```

Comment: thank you so much! now my question is what is the `$h` for? is that the data set?

Comment: Yes, $h is the data set. It's a hash, keyed by the first two characters in each line. The value of each key-value pair is an array, containing an incrementing number [0,1,2...] for each time this key occurs in your file. The size of this array is the frequency of the key. If you uncomment the two Data::Dumper lines, you'll see what data structure has been created.

Comment: oh ok so how would that work if the data set is stored in a file and we need to call to that? would you do the `open($h, '<', filename)` and call to that $h?

Comment: With the `while (<>)`  that I've used, it will open whatever file you name on the command line. Hence `perl tmp.pl tmp.txt`. If you want to put the name of the file into the script, then yes, you do: `open(FILEHANDLE, '<', "filename");` and then change the `(<>)` to `(<FILEHANDLE>)`. The script populates $h.

Comment: it works so far but prints out different values than what is in the file...should i have perl delete whatever is stored as $h?

Comment: Are you sure it's different? It will likely be in a different order.

Comment: I just verified, the data is the same but completely out of order. thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by frequencies, but this code

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;

generate_output(2, 1);
generate_output(2, 3);
generate_output(5, 1);
generate_output(5, 2);
generate_output(5, 3);
generate_output(8, 2);

sub generate_output
{
    my ($a, $b) = @_;

    print "$a $b:";

    my $data_start = tell DATA;

    while (<DATA>) {
        chomp;
        my @columns = split /,/; 
        if ($columns[0] == $a and $columns[1] == $b)
        {
            print " ", $columns[-1];
        }
    }
    print "\n";
    seek DATA, $data_start, 0;
}

__DATA__
2,1,10,2,0
2,1,23,2,1
2,3,6,2,0
5,1,4,3,0
5,2,2,2,0
5,2,2,3,1
5,2,8,1,2
5,3,6,3,1
8,2,12,1,0
```

generates the output you wanted:

```
2 1: 0 1
2 3: 0
5 1: 0
5 2: 0 1 2
5 3: 1
8 2: 0
```

Comment: this helps a lot but i need it to check if the current first 2 elements are equal to the previous first 2 elements (which i found to be near impossible) but was given a hint to have the program find out the frequency of the pairing in the data set and then have pearl print the last value of every row that exact many times and then executes for the next pairing. if were up to me id clean it up for what i have and turn this in but its not what is wanted. thus me just simply asking for finding the frequency of a pairing of numbers then i could implement it. Thank you for the help so far though!:)

Comment: It's still not clear to me what you want - can you update your question to add an example of the input & output you expect ?